# Gremlin query to find connecting scheduled flight routes filtered dynamically on edge properties

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

I am working with scheduled flight routes where I have a date range of when a flight would operate for given day of the week and I need help formulating gremlin query that covers several use case. Schedules route data I am working is as follows and I have about 4000 airports and 5 million scheduled routes. A scheduled route looks like this:

```
Carrier: AA
Flight: 100
Service date from: 2019-02-01 
Service date to: 2019-07-02
Departure: PDX
Arrival: LHR
FlysMonday: true
FlysTuesday: false
...
FlysSunday:false
DepartureDay:0
ArrivalDay:1 <-- overnight flight
```

#### Gremlin query to support use cases:

1. Ability to choose the departing flight based on some criteria for example: Carrier AA, departing on date 2019-1-24 08:00 and before 12:00 from HNL to PDX.
2. Finding connecting flights that have departure time after previous flights arrival time with a minimum connect time buffer ie 90minutes.
3. Handle the case that next connecting flight might departure x days later.
4. Accumulate the total time spent traveling which is total time since departure to arrival including time spent for layovers
5. Find direct flights and any non-direct flights to travel from departure airport to arrival airport.
6. Only fly through a particular airport for layovers ie. LHR to HNL through IAD.

So far I have this and it is pretty slow when I run it against my full graph of 4000 vertices (airports) and 5 million edges (schedule routes). I think part of the problem with this is that I placed the filtering after the traversals.

```
g.V().has('airport', 'name', 'HNL').as('depAirport').repeat(outE().as('flight').inV().as('stop').simplePath()).times(2).emit().has('airport', 'name', 'LHR').filter(select(first, 'flight').and(has('Carrier', 'AA'), has('DepartureTime', gte(Date.parse(timeFormat,'08:00:00'))), has('ServiceDateFrom', lte(Date.parse(dateFormat,'2019-01-24'))), has('ServiceDateTo', gte(Date.parse(dateFormat,'2019-01-24'))))).path().by('name').by(valueMap())
```

Also I am not sure how I could formulate the query so that I can support use case 2, 3, 4 and 6. I am not sure how to only apply the repeat after the first flight if needed for non direct flights between departure and arrival airport.

I tried the following in attempt to trim the departure flight first before the repeat but that yield no results like the other query.

```
g.V().has('airport', 'name', 'HNL').as('depAirport').outE().as('flight').and(has('Carrier', 'AA'), has('DepartureTime', gte(Date.parse(timeFormat,'08:00:00'))), has('ServiceDateFrom', lte(Date.parse(dateFormat,'2019-01-24'))), has('ServiceDateTo', gte(Date.parse(dateFormat,'2019-01-24')))).repeat(inV().as('stop').outE().as('flight').simplePath()).times(2).emit().has('airport', 'name', 'LHR').path().by('name').by(valueMap())
```

#### Here is the graph setup code:

```
dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
timeFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
g = graph.traversal()
g.addV('airport').property('name','PDX').as('PDX').
  addV('airport').property('name','JFK').as('JFK').
  addV('airport').property('name','HNL').as('HNL').
  addV('airport').property('name','ORD').as('ORD').
  addV('airport').property('name','IAD').as('IAD').
  addV('airport').property('name','LHR').as('LHR').
  addV('airport').property('name','CAN').as('CAN').
  addV('airport').property('name','LAX').as('LAX').
  addE('flight').from('HNL').to('PDX').property('Carrier', 'AA').property('FlightNumber', '100').property('ServiceDateFrom', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-01-23')).property('ServiceDateTo', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-03-20')).property('DepartureTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '08:00:00')).property('ArrivalTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '13:00:00')).property('DepartureDay', 0).property('ArrivalDay','0').property('FlysSunday', true).property('FlysMonday', false).property('FlysTuesday', false).property('FlysWednesday', false).property('FlysThursday', false).property('FlysFriday', false).property('FlysSaturday', true).
  addE('flight').from('HNL').to('PDX').property('Carrier', 'AA').property('FlightNumber', '201').property('ServiceDateFrom', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-01-23')).property('ServiceDateTo', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-03-20')).property('DepartureTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '08:00:00')).property('ArrivalTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '13:00:00')).property('DepartureDay', 0).property('ArrivalDay','0').property('FlysSunday', false).property('FlysMonday', true).property('FlysTuesday', true).property('FlysWednesday', true).property('FlysThursday', true).property('FlysFriday', true).property('FlysSaturday', false).
  addE('flight').from('PDX').to('LHR').property('Carrier', 'BA').property('FlightNumber', '100').property('ServiceDateFrom', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-01-31')).property('ServiceDateTo', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-03-05')).property('DepartureTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '13:30:00')).property('ArrivalTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '23:00:00')).property('DepartureDay', 0).property('ArrivalDay','0').property('FlysSunday', true).property('FlysMonday', false).property('FlysTuesday', false).property('FlysWednesday', false).property('FlysThursday', false).property('FlysFriday', false).property('FlysSaturday', true).
  addE('flight').from('PDX').to('LHR').property('Carrier', 'BA').property('FlightNumber', '201').property('ServiceDateFrom', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-02-05')).property('ServiceDateTo', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-03-17')).property('DepartureTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '13:30:00')).property('ArrivalTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '23:00:00')).property('DepartureDay', 0).property('ArrivalDay','0').property('FlysSunday', true).property('FlysMonday', false).property('FlysTuesday', false).property('FlysWednesday', false).property('FlysThursday', false).property('FlysFriday', false).property('FlysSaturday', true).
  addE('flight').from('PDX').to('LHR').property('Carrier', 'BA').property('FlightNumber', '202').property('ServiceDateFrom', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-02-05')).property('ServiceDateTo', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-03-17')).property('DepartureTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '16:00:00')).property('ArrivalTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '02:00:00')).property('DepartureDay', 0).property('ArrivalDay','1').property('FlysSunday', true).property('FlysMonday', false).property('FlysTuesday', false).property('FlysWednesday', false).property('FlysThursday', false).property('FlysFriday', false).property('FlysSaturday', true).
  addE('flight').from('PDX').to('LHR').property('Carrier', 'BA').property('FlightNumber', '203').property('ServiceDateFrom', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-02-05')).property('ServiceDateTo', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-03-17')).property('DepartureTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '16:00:00')).property('ArrivalTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '02:00:00')).property('DepartureDay', 0).property('ArrivalDay','1').property('FlysSunday', false).property('FlysMonday', true).property('FlysTuesday', true).property('FlysWednesday', true).property('FlysThursday', true).property('FlysFriday', true).property('FlysSaturday', false).
  addE('flight').from('ORD').to('PDX').property('Carrier', 'CC').property('FlightNumber', '66').property('ServiceDateFrom', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-08-11')).property('ServiceDateTo', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-12-11')).property('DepartureTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '06:00:00')).property('ArrivalTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '12:00:00')).property('DepartureDay', 0).property('ArrivalDay','0').property('FlysSunday', true).property('FlysMonday', true).property('FlysTuesday', true).property('FlysWednesday', true).property('FlysThursday', true).property('FlysFriday', true).property('FlysSaturday', false).
  addE('flight').from('ORD').to('LAX').property('Carrier', 'CC').property('FlightNumber', '76').property('ServiceDateFrom', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-08-11')).property('ServiceDateTo', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-12-11')).property('DepartureTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '06:00:00')).property('ArrivalTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '12:00:00')).property('DepartureDay', 0).property('ArrivalDay','0').property('FlysSunday', true).property('FlysMonday', true).property('FlysTuesday', true).property('FlysWednesday', true).property('FlysThursday', true).property('FlysFriday', true).property('FlysSaturday', false).
  addE('flight').from('LAX').to('CAN').property('Carrier', 'CC').property('FlightNumber', '12').property('ServiceDateFrom', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-03-11')).property('ServiceDateTo', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-12-24')).property('DepartureTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '15:00:00')).property('ArrivalTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '05:00:00')).property('DepartureDay', 0).property('ArrivalDay','1').property('FlysSunday', false).property('FlysMonday', false).property('FlysTuesday', true).property('FlysWednesday', false).property('FlysThursday', false).property('FlysFriday', false).property('FlysSaturday', true).
  addE('flight').from('PDX').to('CAN').property('Carrier', 'CC').property('FlightNumber', '22').property('ServiceDateFrom', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-03-11')).property('ServiceDateTo', Date.parse(dateFormat, '2019-12-24')).property('DepartureTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '15:00:00')).property('ArrivalTime', Date.parse(timeFormat, '06:00:00')).property('DepartureDay', 0).property('ArrivalDay','1').property('FlysSunday', false).property('FlysMonday', false).property('FlysTuesday', true).property('FlysWednesday', false).property('FlysThursday', false).property('FlysFriday', false).property('FlysSaturday', true).iterate()
```

#### Example query and responses:

Route from HNL to LHR departing 2019-01-24 (Thursday) from 08:00:00 but no later than 12:00:00 with a minimum connect time of 90 minutes should return these:

```
[DepartureAirport: HNL, Flight: AA-201, ConnectingAirport: PDX, Flight: BA-203, ArrivalAirport: LHR, TravelTime: 18hours] <= this is the best route, it meets the minimum connect time buffer of over 90 minutes and has the overall shortest travel time of 18hours which consists of 5hours from HNL to PDX plus 3 hours layover plus 10 hours into LHR. 
[DepartureAirport: HNL, Flight: AA-201, ConnectingAirport: PDX, Flight: BA-201, ArrivalAirport: LHR, TravelTime: 39.5hours] <= this route works but there's a layover in PDX from Thursday until Friday for the BA-201 flight because the same day connecting flight's departure time doesn't meet the minimum connect time buffer from the first leg's arrival time. Total travel time of 39.5 hours consists of 5hours from HNL to PDX, 24.5 hours layover, and 10 hours to LHR.
[DepartureAirport: HNL, Flight: AA-201, ConnectingAirport: PDX, Flight: BA-202, ArrivalAirport: LHR, TravelTime: 90 hours] <= this route works but there's a layover in PDX from Thursday until Sunday for the BA-203 flight. Total travel time of 90 hours consists of 5hours from HNL to PDX, 75hours layover and 10 hours to LHR. I am interested in these as well because there are cases we are routing to  remote airports with infrequent flights.
```

Route from PDX to CAN departing 2019-03-19 (Tuesday) from 16:00:00 but no later than 20:00 with a minimum connect time of 60 minutes should return these direct flights since the sample graph contains only direct flights for this route:

```
[DepartureAirport: PDX, Flight: CC-22, ArrivalAirport: CAN, TravelTime: 14hours] <= this is the best route since it is direct and we don't need to care about the minimum connect time buffer that are only needed if we have a layover.
```

Route from ORD to CAN departing 2019-03-19 (Tuesday) from 16:00:00 but no later than 20:00 with a minimum connect time of 60 minutes and allow only stops via 'LAX' should return this route:

```
[DepartureAirport: ORD, Flight: CC-76, ConnectingAirport: LAX, Flight CC-12, ArrivalAirport: CAN, TravelTime:24hours] <= this is the best route since it satisfies the minimum connect time buffer and it stops via 'LAX'. Total travel time is 24hours consisting of 6hours from ORD to LAX, layover of 3hours and 15hours to CAN.
```

Comment: Can you please provide examples for the other scenarios (input values and expected outputs)?

Comment: Added expected outputs for the other scenarios. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your underlying graph DB? Does it support lambdas? If not, I'd like to change your schema a bit to make calculations for layover times easier.

Comment: I am using AWS Neptune graph database cluster and from their docs, it looks like lambda steps are not supported per: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html

Schema is flexible, welcome any suggestions on how to model the graph vertices and edges for performant queries.

Comment: I spent half my day coming up with a query, but always ended up with a huge block of steps that I couldn't understand myself anymore. I'll try to remodel everything to make querying easier, might take some time though (weekend side-project).

Comment: In your first example, 2 of the travel times are wrong and there's a 4th option missing. The second example should not return any flights (the flight you've mentioned starts at 15:00, but the search criterion is 16:00-20:00). The third example should not return any flights (the flight you've mentioned is not within the service date range).

Comment: Implementing the last few tweaks I just realized that there's no route for the first flight. Why? Because the service start and end-date for the connecting flights are in the future. It would work, but only with a multi-day layover.

Comment: How do you decide which routes are going to be included or excluded from the result? My latest commit focuses on finding the shortest routes (shortest by travel time, not by hops in the graph). This removes some of the routes that were previously part of the result.

Comment: Summary of filtering & ordering criteria: filter results based on if it meets minimum connect time buffer which if not give could vary based on the connecting airlines' given guidelines; whether the route meets the maximum number of connections allowed; filter based on certain attributes of the layover airport such as shuttle transports between connections, whether flights are passenger/cargo/both, whether flights should be operated by multiple carriers or from a single carrier. In the end ordered by first/last flight out of departure airport or first/last flight arriving at arrival airport.

Comment: Thanks for coming up with a code sample for your approach, I very much appreciate it there and I hope it didn't take too much away from your weekend. There is quit a bit there and I will my best try to understand the github repo and will follow up with questions in your answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your current/proposed model is, that the queries need to keep track of so many things and it's really hard to put all that into a single traversal. To make things simpler, I remodeled the graph completely. Flights are now vertices, edges are links to connecting flights. Using this model it made it much easier to keep track of things - all the variables kinda just flow with the traversal. This solution yields the following results:

```
=== Flights from HNL to LHR on 2019-01-24 ===

* Option 1 (1 stop, 18 hours)
  - HNL --[AA-201]-> PDX (Thursday, 2019-01-24 08:00 to 13:00)
    (3 hours layover)
  - PDX --[BA-203]-> LHR (Thursday, 2019-01-24 16:00 to Friday, 2019-01-25 02:00)

* Option 2 (1 stop, 2 days 15 hours)
  - HNL --[AA-201]-> PDX (Thursday, 2019-01-24 08:00 to 13:00)
    (2 days 30 minutes layover)
  - PDX --[BA-201]-> LHR (Saturday, 2019-01-26 13:30 to 23:00)


=== Flights from PDX to CAN on 2019-03-19 ===

* Option 1 (direct, 15 hours)
  - PDX --[CC-22]-> CAN (Tuesday, 2019-03-19 15:00 to Wednesday, 2019-03-20 06:00)


=== Flights from ORD to CAN on 2019-08-20 ===

* Option 1 (1 stop, 23 hours)
  - ORD --[CC-76]-> LAX (Tuesday, 2019-08-20 06:00 to 12:00)
    (3 hours layover)
  - LAX --[CC-12]-> CAN (Tuesday, 2019-08-20 15:00 to Wednesday, 2019-08-21 05:00)
```

As noted in the comments above, I had to change a few things. For the flights from `HNL` to `LHR` I changed some of the service start dates to make the flights available. For the flight from `PDX` to `CAN` I changed the departure time from 16:00 to 15:00. For the flight from `ORD` to `CAN` I changed the date from 2019-03-19 to 2019-08-20 (also a Tuesday).

I posted the project on GitHub: https://github.com/dkuppitz/weiping

The sample graph is generated by [FlightRouteGraph::createSampleGraph()](https://github.com/dkuppitz/weiping/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/weiping/FlightRouteGraph.java#L40), the actual querying is done in [App::findFlights(...)](https://github.com/dkuppitz/weiping/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/weiping/App.java#L116).

Comment: I'm still reviewing through the code and most likely will step through the code locally with a debugger as I'm new to graph databases and gremlin. I wanted to have a quick check with you on the scalability of this approach as I have roughly 4 thousand airports and 5 million flight schedule configurations.  If I understood your approach, I believe there would be 35million flight vertices and 70 million edges connecting for the from/to edges and maybe 35million edges accounting for the computed layovers? From your experience, would this still be feasible/manageable?    Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure about Neptune's scalability, but I've seen graphs much bigger than that.